# different ways of calculating laurent series of $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

it seem to me that in that simple case there are different ways of doing this.

I have to wonder on the general case of $\dfrac{1}{a+z^2}$ at $z=0$.

edit: the interesting part of course is where $|z| > 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to differentiate:
$$\frac1a\frac{d}{dx}\arctan\frac xa=\frac1{a^2+x^2}$$
Use $$\arctan x=x-\frac{x^3}3+\frac{x^5}5-\frac{x^7}7+..$$

Comment: Well, I'm asking of different ways. and this is Taylor. I'm talking about Laurent were |x| also > 1

Comment: @d_e see edit..

Comment: thanks can you elaborate more ?

Comment: Series convergent for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

The usual trick for this case:
$$\dfrac{1}{a+z^2} = \dfrac{1}{z^2}\dfrac{1}{1-(-a/z^2)} = \dfrac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{a^n}{z^{2n}}.$$

Comment: i already tried to tell op that but he said what is the first comment on my post/answer